# How to Modify Only First Nested RecyclerView (child) element at Position 0 of Parent RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I have parentRecyclerview that includes a nestedRecyclerview. nestedRecyclerView lists several items: (Apple, Banana, Pear). I want to **bold** the first item (apple) of this nestedRecyclerview like so:

```
**Apple**
Banana
Pear

-------

Apple
Banana
Pear

-------

Apple
Banana
Pear
```

I can get it to **bold** the first item of each nested recyclerview list by doing:

```
when (position) {
0 -> 
// code to make apple bold
}
```

but that gives me:

```
**Apple**
Banana
Pear

-------

**Apple**
Banana
Pear

-------

**Appla**
Banana
Pear
```

How do I go about this? I would add all my code, but honestly it is a ton of code and much more complex that apples, bananas, pears. I prefer code in Kotlin, but I can figure out Java if thats what you know. Thanks!

Lots of internet searching done, but most talk about onClickListener events.

Comment: your parent recyclerview gives indexes to its nested recyclerviews just pass the index to the nested recyclerview's adapter and check if the index is equal to zero and the position of the item (as you write with `when` block) is equals to zero then make it bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this create variable to manage bold of view based on position

```
class NestedAdapter(...) {
private var topItemBold = false

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NestedViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]

    if (topItemBold && position == 0) {
        holder.textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
    } else {
        holder.textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL)
    }

    // ... rest of your binding logic
}
```

and update your parent adapter like this

```
class ParentAdapter(...) {
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ParentViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val nestedAdapter = holder.nestedRecyclerView.adapter as NestedAdapter

    if (position == 0) {
        nestedAdapter.topItemBold = true
    } else {
        nestedAdapter.topItemBold = false
    }
}
```

so in above our `topItemBold` only true for first item on nested view on first item of parent list

Comment: Incredible! Thank you! Just had to change the variable "private var topItemBold = false" to public instead and it worked perfectly.